# need help to resolve - Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I know there are many questions/tutorials for this subject, but cannot solve my problem.
I have to ask for your help. Second day cannot find out the solution to this simple problem.

I am trying as in this tutorial - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/
That is working fine, but once i try from DB, i am getting error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**"

Here is my web page

```
@model testEmpty.Models.Address

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/myScripts/myScripts.js"></script>

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Address</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            @Html.Label("Zone")
            @Html.DropDownList("ZoneId", ViewBag.ZoneName as SelectList, "--Select a Zone--", new { id = "ZoneId" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Zone", "*")
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.Label("Districts of SZ")
                    <select id="DistrictSZ" name="DistrictSZ"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller

```
private myContext db = new myContext();

// GET: Addresses
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var zones = db.Addresses.Include(a => a.Zone);

    ViewBag.ZoneName = new SelectList(zones, "Value", "Text");

    return View(zones.ToList());
}

public JsonResult DistrictList(int id)
{
    var district = from s in db.Districts
                   where s.ZoneId == id
                   select s;

    return Json(new SelectList(district.ToArray(), "ZoneId", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('#ZoneId').change(function () {
        $.getJSON('DistrictList/' + $('#ZoneId').val(), getDistricts (data));
    });
});

function getDistricts(data) {
    var items = '<option>Select a District</option>';
    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
        items += "<option value='" + district.Value + "'>" + district.Text + "</option>";
    });
    $('#DistrictSZ').html(items);
}
```

As i understand, my problem is with JSON. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the returned value of `getDistricts` to the callback variable of `$.getJSON`.

```
$.getJSON('DistrictList/' + $('#ZoneId').val(), getDistricts (data));
```

You need to pass the function reference like this

```
$.getJSON('DistrictList/' + $('#ZoneId').val(), getDistricts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you do not need to return a `SelectList` (javascript knows nothing about a c# class)

```
public JsonResult DistrictList(int id)
{
  var district = db.Districts.Where(d => d.ZoneId == id).Select(d => new
  {
    Value = d.ZoneId, // this look wrong - see note below
    Text = d.Name
  });
  return Json(district, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in your script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DistrictList")'; // ensure your url's are properly generated
var districts = $('#DistrictSZ'); // cache it
$('#ZoneId').change(function () {
  $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
    districts.empty(); // remove existing options
    districts.append($('</option>').val('').text('Select a District'));
    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
      districts.append($('</option>').val(district.Value).text(district.Text));
    });
  });
});
```

In fact, since `ZoneId` is always the same, you could just return a collection of the `Name` values

```
 var district = db.Districts.Where(d => d.ZoneId == id).Select(d => d.Name);
```

and

```
$('#ZoneId').change(function () {
  var zoneID = $(this).val();
  $.getJSON(url, { id: zoneID }, function(data) {
    districts.empty(); // remove existing options
    districts.append($('</option>').val('').text('Select a District'));
    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
      districts.append($('</option>').val(zoneID).text(district));
    });
  });
});
```

However your code is generating all options with the same value (`ZoneId`) which does not make much sense, so I suspect you really want to use another property of `District` - i.e. its `Id` (or `DistrictId`?) property.

Comment: The SQL selection is - SELECT Districts.id, Districts.Name from Districts Where Districts.ZoneId = ID.

Comment: Which means that your original code would have needed to be `new SelectList(district.ToArray(), "Id", "Name")` - not `"ZoneId` In my answer you need to change it to `Value = d.Id` (not `Value = d.ZoneId`)

Comment: structure of script is not correct. i tried as following, is that correct? var url = '@Url.Action("DistrictList")'; 
var districts = $('#Districts'); // cache it
$('#ZoneId').change(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, {
        id: $(this).val(),
        data: function (data) {
            districts.empty(); // remove existing options
            districts.append($('</option>').val('').text('Select a District'));
            $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                districts.append($('</option>').val(district.Value).text(district.Text));
            });
        }
    });
});

Comment: Oops - I left out a `}` in `$.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {` - see update

Comment: Code is working with no errors. But in the end, my "DistrictSZ" is empty. It is not updating it. I checked data putting an alert(), it is OK with Value & Text (Name in my case). What is missing ?

Comment: Sorry, another typo - in the `DistrictList()` it should be `Text = d.Name` (not `Name - d.Name`) - see update, or else in the view change it to `districts.append($('</option>').val(district.Value).text(district.Name));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80499/discussion-between-ado-kg-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should handle your callback function with a anonymous function like this:

```
$.getJSON('DistrictList/' + $('#ZoneId').val(), success(data){
    getDistricts(data);
})
```